# Excel Ribbon Custom Add-in tab

Tags: excel, add-in, ribbon

We have an excel add-in that has generated it's own tab (for years - since at least Excel 2007) and put it's icons in place -

But now we are trying to make it work with Excel 2016 and have into a strange one
Instead of putting it in out custom tab named 'ourTabName" and putting in large icons, it is installing in a tab called "Add-ins" and using small icons.

Does anyone know if something changed with 2016, and how we fix this?

Comment: Maybe it installs toolbar (command bars) or ribbon UI depending on the version of Excel? And in case of 2016, version is detected incorrectly (maybe because it's installed as "office 365" for example)

Comment: A lot has changed. How have you generated the custom tab prior?